# Another shorten SQL string? c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select

Some may already be noticing this and I would like to confirm it, I am really inexperienced with complex SQL strings. I only know simple SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE and DELETE statements. And to achieve my purpose I often use 2 SELECT statements, like this one :

```
con.Open();
string cmdstr = "SELECT UNIQUE FROM recipeList WHERE `stock_ID` = '" + stockIDTxtbox.Text + "'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string menuID = "";
while (dr.Read())
{
   menuID = (dr["menu_ID"].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();

con.Open();
string cmdstr = "SELECT `menu_name` FROM recipedb WHERE `menu_ID` = '" + menuID + "'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string menuName = "";
while (dr.Read())
{
    menuName = (dr["menu_name"].ToString());
    this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{ menuName  }))
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Any ideas how to shorten this? o.O

Comment: Holy Sql Injection vulnerablity, Batman!

Comment: use a join.....and what Joel said!

Comment: As Joel and Mitch have already pointed out you have a massive SQL Injection problem. If you're not sure what SQL Injection is, have a look at http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html for a good intro and how to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write an SQL as:

```
 string queryString =  "SELECT r2.menu_name "+
                       "FROM recipelist rl "+ 
                          "INNER JOIN recipedb r2 "+
                          "ON rl.menu_ID = r2.menu_ID "+
                       "WHERE r1.stock_ID = '" + stockIDTxtbox.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't written SQL in a while but it should be a join, so something like the following:

```
select rdb.menu_name
from recipedb rdb, 
     recipelist rl
where rl.menu_ID = rdb.menu_ID and
      rl.stock_ID = * insert your stockIDTxtbox.Text in here without the stars *
```

Comment: Ugh. The "," syntax for joins is really not recommended.

Comment: Why is that kind of syntax not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short one:

```
con.Open();
string cmdstr = "SELECT menu_name FROM recipedb WHERE menu_ID in (SELECT UNIQUE menu_id from recipeList WHERE stock_ID = '" + stockIDTxtbox.Text + "')";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string menuName = "";
while (dr.Read())
{
   menuName = (dr["menu_name"].ToString());
   this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{ menuName  }))
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: what's the difference in this sql string from the INNER JOINed ones?